# In which of the intervals is $\sqrt{12}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, radicals, irrational-numbers, number-comparison

In which of the intervals is $\sqrt{12}:$

*a)* $(2.5;3);$

*b)* $(3;3.5);$

*c)* $(3.5;4);$

*d)*
$(4;4.5)$?

We can use a calculator and find that $\sqrt{12}\approx3.46$ so the correct answer is actually *b*. How can we think about the problem without a calculator (if on exam for example)? I was able to conclude that $$\sqrt{9}=3<\sqrt{12}<\sqrt{16}=4,\\3<\sqrt{12}<4,\\\sqrt{12}\in\left(3;4\right).$$ How can I further constrict the interval? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you know that you can find square of something ending in 5 easily. Like $15^2=225$ or $75^2=5625$ and $35^2=1225$. I hope you have noticed the pattern.

Comment: Take the squares of the interval endpoints rather than computing the square root.

Comment: Newton's formula is the fastest way:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\left(\frac{7}2 \right)^2 = \frac{49}{4}>12>3^2$$

Hence the solution is $B$.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I really don't see how are we using the fact that $(3.5)^2>12,$ though.

Comment: If $3.5^2 > 12 > 3^2$, we have $3.5 > \sqrt{12} > 3$.

Comment: Thank you! Can we always take square roots when working with inequalities?

Comment: Only when $a,b$ are both positive. To see why $a^2 > b^2$ does not imply $a > b$, $(-5)^2 > 3$ but $-5 < 3$.

Answer (score 1):

The smallest integer square greater than $12$ is $4^2 = 16$, and the largest integer square less than $12$ is $3^2 = 9$.  Therefore, $3 < \sqrt{12} < 4$.  This eliminates (a) and (d) as choices.  The next thing to do is consider the value of $(3.5)^2$, which is $$(3 + 1/2)^2 = 9 + 2(3)(1/2) + (1/2)^2 = 12 + 1/4 > 12.$$  Hence $$3 < \sqrt{12} < 3.5.$$

Comment: Thank you for the response! How exactly are we using the fact that $3.5^2>12$. I don't see it, sorry.

Comment: @Medi If $(3.5)^2 > 12$, then taking square roots gives us $3.5 > \sqrt{12}$.  Combined with the previous knowledge that $3 < \sqrt{12} < 4$, it follows that $3 < \sqrt{12} < 3.5$.

Comment: Thank you! Can we always take square roots when working with inequalities?

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt{12} = 3 + (\sqrt{12} - 3) = 3 + \frac{(\sqrt{12})^2 - 3^2}{\sqrt{12} + 3} = 3+\frac{3}{\sqrt{12}+3}$$

and since $3 < \sqrt{12} < 4$, $\frac{3}{3 + 4} < \frac{3}{\sqrt{12} + 3} < \frac{3}{3 + 3}$. Thus $\sqrt{12} < 3 + \frac{1}{2}$ so $b$ is correct.

Comment: In fact, you can repeat this process to find an infinite continued fraction for the square root of any number. The successive continued fraction approximations give lower and upper bounds on the square root.

Answer (score 1):

Building upon what Siong already said. For numbers **greater than one**, the square function is an increasing function. This means that if

$$a>b$$

then

$$a^2>b^2$$

eg

$$5<6$$

$$25<36$$

(this doesn't apply for numbers less than 1, you can try yourself)

Applying the same logic but in reverse, find squares of all options and figure out in which interval you will find 12. Taking square root will give you the original options and  $sqrt12$ in the interval

Comment: This doesn't add anything new to what others have said.

Answer (score 1):

$3^2=9.$

$3.5^2 = \frac{35}{10} \times \frac{35}{10} = \frac{35 \times 35}{100} = \frac{1225}{100} = 12.25.$

$9 < 12 < 12.25.$

$\sqrt{9} < \sqrt{12} < \sqrt{12.25}.$

$3< \sqrt{12} < 3.5.$

Answer (score 1):

There is still a faster way :)

**Tool:** [Newton's well-known formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method)

If $\sqrt a=n, ~n \in\mathbb R^{+}\setminus \mathbb Q^{+}$ and $\lfloor \sqrt a \rfloor=m$, then

$$\sqrt a <\frac{ \dfrac am +m}{2}≈\sqrt a$$

So, you can get the answer right away:

$$\sqrt {12}<\frac{ \dfrac {12}{3} +3}{2}=3.5$$